# Dropbox API - Are the File IDs unique?

Tags: api, dropbox

We are using the dropbox REST API to migrate file from dropbox repo to our platform. But the thing is that different files have same IDs, we are using the IDs and path to create the folder/file hierarchy and replicate the same in our platform. Now, because of this issue, some files are seen in different folders and not in the expected folder. Is this a bug or should we rely on the file paths entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File IDs in the Dropbox API are indeed expected to be unique. That is, files at two different paths shouldn't simultaneously have the same ID.

If you are seeing that, that would be a bug, which you can report here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/contact

However, note that file IDs are case sensitive, and it's possible for some file IDs to differ only be case, so make sure you're using case-sensitive comparisons.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue, we were using upper case Ids till now, thanks for the timely reply.